Update Description attribute through BIM360 API
Is there any way to update  "Description" field of the files in ACC through bim360 API calls?
It is to be noted that "Description" in my ACC is not a custom attribute. I understand, https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/update-custom-attribute-values/ is for custom attributes.

For anyone else trying this, it is not a supported feature yet. Also relevant: Autodesk Construction Cloud - Get file Description attribute

Currently, none of the Autodesk APIs support this. It is, however, on the wishlist under ticket: 'FDM-3886 - Allow modification of [Description] field for Items' to be availed. We will update once this is ready for public release.
Ref: Patch item to update description
